# In Kafka, how to deliberately delay the acknowledgment from Kafka to Producer (for testing purposes)?

Tags: apache-kafka

Kafka producer(librdkafka) produces messages to Kafka(server) and Kafka sends acknowledgment(delivery report) to Producer once msg is written to it's data files.

For testing purposes, I want to delay the reception of ack (i.e. Delivery success callback firing at producer application side).
As I understand producer config linger.ms does NOT guarantee delay for any msg, rather it collects and sends data periodically in linger.ms intervals.

Is there way to deliberately delay the acknowledgment from Kafka to Producer (for testing purposes) ?